# How to check logged in and open Modal with Pjax?

Tags: php, jquery, yii2, pjax

I has module: LIKE. I want check logged in , When not logged in, it will open modal Login. I had modal Login.

My button Like:

```
<?php \yii\widgets\Pjax::begin() ?>
  <a href="<?php echo Url::to(['site/like', 'id' => $post->id, 'type' => ArticleLike::TYPE_LIKE_BLOG]) ?>" data-method="post" data-pjax="1" class="box-like1 <?php echo ArticleLike::isLikedBlog(Yii::$app->user->id, $post->id) ? 'btn btn-danger': 'btn btn-secondary' ?>"><i class="far fa-heart"></i></a>
<?php \yii\widgets\Pjax::end() ?>
```

Controller Like:

```
public function actionLike($id, $type)
    {
        $userId = \Yii::$app->user->id;
        $queryLike = ArticleLike::find()
            ->andWhere([
                'user_id' => $userId,
                'article_id' => $id
            ])
            ->one();
        if (!$queryLike) {
            $this->saveLike($id, $userId, $type);
        } else if ($queryLike->type == $type) {
            $queryLike->delete();
        } else {
            $queryLike->delete();
            $this->saveLike($id, $userId, $type);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Help me. Thank all.

Comment: Where is your jQuery code?

Comment: I haven't used JQuery because I don't know JQuery login testing @FSDford

Comment: Put your login testing in a php file that you call like this 

$('button[type="submit"]').click(function(event){

    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        success: function(data, status, xhr) {

            $('#modal-div').modal('close');

        },
        url: ...,
        ...

    })
})

Comment: @FSDford Can you describe more specifically. I using modal bootstrap Login Form

Comment: Your English is not clear.  Try to find a demo on jsfiddle or another sandbox that shows the UI experience and possibly has a code chuck or snippet that will inch you one step closer to the answer.  It is much easier to solve a problem like this with generated HTML.